# Why I am getting wrong bytes when converting struct to byte array?

Tags: c++, struct

I was trying to convert a c++ struct variable to a byte array. But unfortunately, I am getting a weird output.

**Code:**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

struct A{
    int  x; 
};

int main ()
{
    A obj;
    obj.x = 892323;

    char *x =(char *)malloc(sizeof(obj));
    memcpy(x, (unsigned char *)&obj, sizeof(obj));

    for(int i=0; i < sizeof(obj); i++)
        printf("%02X\n",x[i]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
FFFFFFA3
FFFFFF9D
0D
00
```

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this kind out output?

Comment: Read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf, and then stop using `printf`.

Comment: Why do you think the output is weird or wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The output is correct, even if not be what you would expect. The underlying cause is that it is implementation defined whether the `char` type is signed or unsigned. In your platform, it is signed so the byte `0xA3` is -93. When you pass it to the `printf` function it is promoted to an `int`. But the `%x` modifier will convert it to an unsigned value by adding 0x100000000 when int (and unsigned int) use 32 bits to give 4294967203 or 0xffffffa3.

If you want to get only 2 character per byte, you should use `unsigned char`. With

```
...
unsigned char* x = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(obj));
...
```

You would get:

```
A3
9D
0D
00
```

which is indeed the byte representation of 892323 or 0xd9da3 on a little endian system with 32 bits integers.

BTW, your code heavily uses the C standard library. While it is not wrong because the C++ standard explicitely includes it in the C++ standard library there are 2 weak points:

- your code cannot benefit of all the type safety provided by the C++ language and its library
- you will fail to learn how to use modern C++